# Create many lists from list of dictionaries that have different structures

Tags: python

I have a big list of dictionaries. And the dictionaries don´t have the same structure. But, I don´t know all the structures (my list has 1 million elements).

For example:

```
mylist = [{'name': 'Juan Carlos','age':38},{'name':'David','country':'Brazil'},
          {'name':'Agustina', 'country': 'Argentina'},{'name': 'Renzo','age':24}]
```

I want to separate `mylist` into different lists, and each list has dictionaries with the same keys.

For example:

```
list1 = [{'name': 'Juan Carlos','age':38},{'name': 'Renzo','age':24}]
list2 = [{'name':'David','country':'Brazil'},{'name':'Agustina', 'country': 'Argentina'}]
```

The problem is I don´t know how many sublists I'm going to have.

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need to create a dictionary where the key is the set of keys that are present:

```
mylist = [{'name': 'Juan Carlos','age':38},{'name':'David','country':'Brazil'},{'name':'Agustina', 'country': 'Argentina'},{'name': 'Renzo','age':24}]

sublists = {}

for sl in mylist:
    keys = tuple(set(sl.keys()))
    if keys not in sublists:
        sublists[keys] = []
    sublists[keys].append( sl )

print( sublists )
```

Output:

```
{('name', 'age'): [{'name': 'Juan Carlos', 'age': 38}, {'name': 'Renzo', 'age': 24}], ('name', 'country'): [{'name': 'David', 'country': 'Brazil'}, {'name': 'Agustina', 'country': 'Argentina'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) of keys as a new key:

```
mylist = [{'name': 'Juan Carlos','age':38},{'name':'David','country':'Brazil'},
          {'name':'Agustina', 'country': 'Argentina'},{'name': 'Renzo','age':24}]

sep = {}
for d in mylist:
    sep.setdefault(frozenset(d), []).append(d)
```

and then you can get a list of lists:

```
print(sep.values())
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! Both solutions work super well!